# Why custom dependency-properties in custom class in WPF could be assigned by different values while creating objects of this class?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I am studying WPF now and have a problem with underatanding DependencyProperty. What I mean by this, DependencyProperty object is always declared as **public static readonly**. For example:

```
    public class Phone : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty;
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PriceProperty;

        static Phone()
        {
            TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Phone));
            PriceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Price", typeof(int), typeof(Phone));
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }
        public int Price
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(PriceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PriceProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

But when I use this class in XAML by creating Phone objects, I can assign **static** fields
of this class in two different objects by different values:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Phone Price="600" Title="iPhone 6S" x:Key="iPhone6s" />
        <local:Phone Price="601" Title="iPhone 7S" x:Key="iPhone7s" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

And if I want to show information about these objects on a Grid, I will see, that in these objects their **static** DependencyProperties Title and Price have different values. I know, that if class has static field, the value of this field will be equal for all objects of this class, but it doesn't work here. Why?

Comment: GetValue and SetValue are instance methods of the DependencyObject class. They get and set a value on a DependencyObject instance. That's why you can declare the property wrappers Title and Price as non-static properties.

Comment: The backing store is static, but the values stored therein are mapped to the instance and property they belong to. The access goes via the non-static methods SetValue and GetValue.
The backing store is static because the dependency property registration works on the type not the instance.

Comment: It is not the "backing store" that is static, but the *identifier field*. Property values are stored at the instance level. Greatly simplified, you can think of DependencyObject as kind of a dictionary that accesses property values by identifier fields as keys.